# Are there any ways to make an object count as a creature, even briefly?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, objects

Objects are not creatures.

(We will ignore the undefined question of corpses....)

The object needs to remain an object, if possible. Polymorph is not an option, regardless, due to a requirement of not actually turning the object into a creature. The idea is to make it a valid target without actually changing it into a creature - it needs to remain an object.

Are there any methods which can cause an object to temporarily count as a creature for the purpose of targeting it with an effect that targets creatures?

---

The context is that we are trying to target an object wth a destructive effect that does not affect objects, while attempting to avoid the potential moral, ethical, and or religious / alignment factors inherent in changing an object into a creature then destroying / killing it.

Comment: So you want it to be both an object and a creature at the same time?

Comment: Context would be useful. For example, is there a reason *polymorph any object* doesn't work?  That should let a wizard turn a dude into an ottoman or a carrot or whatever long enough to put on the piece of furniture or the vegetable or whatever a *symbol of stunning* or a *teleportation circle*; then it's just a *dispel magic* and the dude has new cool magic tats. (That's not a stealth answer but me acknowledging the expertise the asker's demonstrated in the past; *PAO* seems too obvious to be an actual solution—I'm more interested in the question adding context.)

Comment: In short we are trying to morally and ethically destroy an object with an effect that doesn't target objects... see updated question for details.

Comment: You should specify you require it to not *actually* become a creature, otherwise making it one (e.g. via *animate objects*) is the best answer.

Comment: Updated as per your suggestion

Answer (score 5):

Animate Objects is capable of giving objects creature status.
    http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/animateObjects.htm

Comment: The *MM* says, "Anything with no Wisdom score is an object, not a creature" (312). Animated objects have Wis 1. (Once the *animate object* spell ends, though, they'll be objects again.)

Comment: @Hey I Can Chan I'm confused by your comment. The OP asked about temporarily counting as a creature.

Comment: The question says, "The object needs to remain an object, if possible.… The idea is to make it a valid target *without* actually changing it into a creature." When the object is subject to the *animate objects* spell, the object becomes a creature. Like the *polymorph any object* spell, when the spell's duration expires the subject will be what it was originally, but the asker wants the subject to be simultaneously *both* object *and* creature, which may be impossible. (Although this is *3.5*, so there's probably a way somewhere.)