# Is a corpse a possess-able object?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, animated-objects, possession

Creatures with the fiend of possession prestige class progressively gain a wider range of control over inanimate material and objects (eventually even very loosely defined objects).

> Possess Object (Su): A fiend of possession in ethereal form can possess an object on the Material Plane… A fiend of possession becomes part of the object it possesses, so it is no longer ethereal. The fiend is aware of what is going on around the object: It can see and hear up to 60 feet away as if using its normal senses (it does not gain blindsight). While possessing an object, a fiend of possession can use any ability it has that requires no physical action… until it reaches a high enough level to make the possessed object perform these tasks for it.

> Control Object (Su): When possessing an object with some inherent mobility, a fiend of possession of at least 3rd level can control the object's movement. The fiend can cause a vehicle or similar object to move at a speed up to the fiend's own land speed in its corporeal form. Other moving parts-such as a clock's hands or a crossbow's firing mechanism-are under the fiend's control. Thus, a fiend could make a wagon steer toward a pedestrian, or roll out of a stable without a horse to pull it.”

> Animate Object (Su): At 4th level, a fiend of possession gains the ability to force an object with no inherent moving parts to animate, effectively animating it as with the animate objects spell. See the description of animated objects in the Monster Manual.

> Possess Noncontinuous Object (Su): At 5th level, a fiend of possession can use its possess object ability to take control of an "object" more loosely defined: a pool of water, a cloud of dust, or a section of wall or floor.

Now the spell Animate Objects states “an animated object can be of any nonmagical material -wood, metal, stone. fabric, leather, ceramic, glass, or the like..” and the entry in MM states “Objects with two legs (statues, ladders) or a similar shape that allows faster movement have a +10 foot bonus to speed.”

So my question is, can a fiend of possession possess a corpse (as an object) and if so, at what level? Does it have inherit mobility because it has legs (3rd level)? Does it qualify for animated possession at 4th, because the matter is not magical, and the open ended materials listed?  If not then, does it qualify at the 5th level, when the fiend can possess loosely defined objects?

I assume the ability would not function in the exact same way as the Dybbuk, but it’s ability makes me think such a feat should be possible.

Comment: You may be interested in [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/36105/8610), [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/107744/8610), or even [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/160918/8610). Has the DM ruled whether or not the [*Main FAQ*](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/60044/8610) will be used as a rules source in the campaign?

Comment: Thank you for these references.